# Android signed apk (.aab) rejected from Play Store.`app is not compliant with how REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission is allowed.`

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, google-play-console, hybrid-mobile-app

Issue found: Permission use is not directly related to your app's core purpose.
We found that your app is not compliant with how REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission is allowed to be used. Specifically, the use of the permission is not directly related to the core purpose of the app.

I'm just using these permission in my `AndroidManiFest` file

```
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Moreover, not using/define any package named `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` in `pubspec.yaml`, even didn't found that word `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` in my project

Trying to resolve this error and upload my app on play store

Comment: See if this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73924777/10034413

Answer (score 0):

try this in your manifest

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"
    tools:node="remove" />
```

Comment: I tried it and getting error because of 'tools' attribute in it.
to use the 'tools' attribute in 'uses-permission' we have to define 'tools' tag in main tag of 'AndroidManifest.xml'
`<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.taskshift_v1"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">`

Answer (score 0):

Error resolved. I was using the [open_file](https://pub.dev/packages/open_file) which requires the REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES and that was the reason of rejection from the play store.
To resolve this I used [open_filex](https://pub.dev/packages/open_filex) instead of [open_file](https://pub.dev/packages/open_file) because the open_filex package is fork of open_file and its basically develop to resolve the issue of open_file package.
Moreover, I make some changes in AndroidManifest.xml file to remove this REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission, mentioned below:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"  tools:node="remove"/>`

for the above line you also have to define "tools" attribute in the open tag of AndroidManifest.xml

`<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.xxxx.xxxxxxx" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">`

NOTE: Make sure that your app doesn't used the package which require REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission because we remove this permission through the above code